# Unable to close a popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

A popup with `class=.team-popup` opens up on click of `class=".team-single"`
I am unable to close the pop up on click of `class=.close-btn`

Following is the JS and html code

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

  jQuery(".team-single").click(function() {
    jQuery(".team-popup").show();
  });

  jQuery(".close-btn").click(function() {
    jQuery(".team-popup").hide();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="team-single">
  <div class="team-popup">
    <div class="popup-box">
      <div class="col-sm-8 col-xs-7 right-side">

      </div>
      <span class="close-btn">x close</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- single team ends-->
```

Please help me out

Comment: The code looks fine, why isn't this working?

Comment: Is the popup being added by an async operation or at any time after the document ready has been triggered?

Comment: you should prevent the event from bubbling, when you click the ".close-btn" the click bubble to the ".team-single". use event.stopPropagation()

Comment: @CrisimIlNumenoreano I was about to post an answer with that. Why don't you go ahead and post it yourself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in javascript all events (well, almost) "bubble" out to the parents elements.

in you sample code the "click" event reach the ".team-single" bounded function cause of this bubbling.

you should prevent the bubbling by using the stopPropagation function of the event object.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

  jQuery(".team-single").click(function(e) {
    jQuery(".team-popup").show();
  });

  jQuery(".close-btn").click(function(e) {
    jQuery(".team-popup").hide();
    e.stopPropagation();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see by the comment your html structure should be modified. 
Here is an example

```
<html>
<body>

<div class="team-single">
    <div class="open-popup">open</div>
    <div class="team-popup" style="display:none">
        <div class="popup-box">
            <div class="col-sm-8 col-xs-7 right-side">
               text inside your popup
            </div>
            <span class="close-btn">x close</span>
        </div>
   </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    jQuery(".open-popup").click(function(){
        jQuery(".team-popup").show();
    });

    jQuery(".close-btn").click(function(){
        jQuery(".team-popup").hide();
    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: although this surely works, it doesn't clarify why OP code doesn't work.

Comment: I guess that the explanation above are quite accurate. My explanation is that the two listeners are attached to a common area that's why a loop is created and a stop propagation is needed

Comment: Actually I would say that @crisim-il-numenoreano answer is a hack  and for all the times I used a hack I could say is not a good solution